# If $g (x)= \int_0 ^{x^2} f(t)\, dt = x\ln(x)$, find $f(1)$

Tags: calculus

> If $g (x)= \displaystyle\int_0 ^{x^2} f(t)\, dt = x\ln(x)$, find $f(1)$.

I know the answer is $1/2$, but how do you get that? I thought that you would plug $1$ into $x\ln(x)$ and get $\ln(1)$ which would be zero. Why is the answer not zero?

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of an integral with respect to the upper limit is the value of the integrand at the upper limit.  You are given $g(x)=\int_0^{x^2}f(t)\; dt=x \ln(x)$  Then $\left.\frac {dg(x)}{d(x^2)}\right |_{x^2=1}=f(1)$  You will need to use the chain rule.

Comment: I don't understand that though. Could you please work out the problem for me and explain step by step what you did? I have a final tomorrow and this is a problem from one of the exams given a few years ago.

Comment: As you raise the upper limit of an integral, you add a strip of area.  If you are computing $\int_a^x f(t)\;dt$ and increase $x$ by $\Delta x$, you add a strip that is $\Delta x \times f(x)$, so the derivative of the integral is the integrand at the upper limit.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't really help me much.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int_0^x f(t)\, dt = \sqrt{x} \ln \sqrt{x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\int^{x^2}_0f(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\ln x\right)\\
\implies \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}(x^2)}\left(\int^{x^2}_0f(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)\times\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x^2\right)=\ln x+1\\
\implies 2xf(x^2)=\ln x+1\\
\implies 2f(1)=0+1\\
\implies f(1)=\dfrac{1}{2}$$